# How do I make a function read a row and a column with only zeros without using libraries

Tags: python, matrix

I'm new to programming in general... I have to check all the rows and columns of an matrix and in case any of them are complete with zeros, return a True value. I made this code in a silly attempt but it doesn't work for the purpose of the question itself. The matrix will always be a square and a list of lists.

```
def determinanteEhNulo(matriz):
  contador = 0
  
  for i in matriz:
    for j in range(len(matriz)):
      if i[j] == 0:
        contador += 1

  if contador >= int(len(matriz)):
    return True
  return False
```

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful. Is it a numpy array, list of lists, or something else? Is matrix guaranteed to be square? etc

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you want the result to be? You say you want to "check" but that doesn't describe what you really need.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Matrix will always be a square, and it will be a list of lists

Comment: Use `for j in i: if j==0:`

Comment: I want the result to be True if any row or column is complete with zeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you need.

```
def determinanteEhNulo(matriz):
    for i in matriz:
        if all(x==0 for x in i):
            return True
    for i in zip(*matriz):
        if all(x==0 for x in i):
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: you should use `any(x!=0 for x in i)`. Lots of non 0 things evaluate to falsy in Python...

Comment: agreed, an integer list cannot necessarily be assumed.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
def determinanteEhNulo(matrix):
    global count
    for i in matrix:
       if all([j ==0 for j in i]):
          count += 1
                
    if count == len(matrix):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.